# make all the textbox in vertically aligned in web form in ASP.NET using Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am new to Web developing. Before it I worked with C# in that there is an option **Format=>Align=> Horizontal/Vertical** but while working with web Application it Shows like disable.
.
So my Query is ..How I can Make my all textbox vertically aligned??

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use CSS to align your text boxes.

A Google search should provide any details you need.

There are also articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842194/css-aligning-elements-inside-a-div) in stack overflow that can explain how to align elements with CSS.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842194/css-aligning-elements-inside-a-div)

Comment: is there any shortcut like Windows form or i have to code CSS for it??

Comment: There is no shortcut I know of.  ASP.NET different from Windows Forms.  MS worked hard to make the transition as easy as possible, but the technologies have fundamental differences.  Windows Forms uses its own rendering engine, but  ASP.NET outputs HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that are all rendered by a browser.  The best way to format and align ASP.NET is with CSS.